# Problem replacing Slater Pilot Switch with Leviton

Tags: pilot-light

I have an existing Slater Pilot Switch with two terminals on each side (dismissing the ground). [image]

[image: Slater]

An existing black is split in the box and wired into either side, a separate black and white are wired into the other terminals on each side. The switch controls a single light in an attic and the pilot is on when the light is on, which I want to replicate. As far as I can tell, there are no other lights or switches, so I believe it to be a single pole.

The new switch I purchased is a Leviton with just three terminals. [image]. I am at a loss as to how to translate the existing wiring of the Slater to the Leviton. I suspect I need to eliminate the split black wire, which appears to be no longer necessary. Thoughts? Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The new switch is just the same as the old switch except that the connection between the switch's load terminal and the hot side of the pilot light is internal to the new switch. This internal connection replaces the split done with the wirenut.

Here's how your existing switch is wired:
[image]

The single black wire is the Hot wire. The white wire is the Neutral. The split black wire goes to the Load and also supplies power to the pilot light.

New here's a diagram of the new switch:
[image]

As you can see, it's exactly the same except the extra connection is internal to the body of the switch.

Let’s label the wires coming to the switch. The black that is not split is Hot, the black that is split is Load and the white wire is Neutral.

Remove the old switch and the split on the Load.

Connect the Hot to the black screw.

Connect the Load to the brass screw.

Connect the Neutral to the silver screw.

Of course, also connect the ground to the green screw.

Done.

Note: the configuration of the new switch is shown by my previous mistake that had him connect the Hot to the brass screw. He reported that the pilot was on regardless of the switch position. With the mistake, the light was directly between Hot and Neutral. I am confident that this answer is now completely correct.

Comment: I think he has a neutral on the old switch.

Comment: @JACK Thanks. I realized that as I was continuing my answer.

Comment: Stay safe out there +

Comment: Thanks to you both. I finally had a chance to implement today following these directions, and it's partially successful. The switch is installed and works the light correctly but the pilot light is lit all the time.Additional thoughts?

Comment: @JACK, I should have tagged you in my comment above. Thanks.

Comment: I have a follow-up question for @DoxyLover regarding the pilot switch

Comment: @MarcGoldstein I don’t know. Only thing I can think of is to try removing the light from the socket temporarily and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @DoxyLover I did some additional looking around and it appears that the location of the load, hot, and neutral impact the operation of the pilot (always on, on when the bulb is lit, and off when the bulb is lit). I reversed the hot and load and it works as I desire now.

Comment: Of course. My mistake. The split would have to be the load so that the original pilot was controlled by the switch. I’ll revise the answer.

Comment: Actually, thinking further, you demonstrated that I was wrong about how the new switch/light worked. It's simply a switch and light, like before, with an internal connection between the load side of the switch and the light. I'm going to go back and really clean up my answer.